# Py4JJavaError running Pyspark program

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm doing a short application that tells you which is the most popular hero out of a big dataset of Marvel movies based on their number of appearances.

I've installed Pyspark from the Anaconda environment and also from console to try and solve this error without results. I also installed the Java-jdk for conda but no results neither.

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.partitions.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 2018:19
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 2018:19
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
    ... 30 more
```

And here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar 20 13:33:45 2019

@author: Carlos
"""
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("personaje_mas_popular")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

def numerocoapariciones(linea):
    elementos = linea.split()
    return (int(elementos[0]), len(elementos)-1)

def codificarnombres(linea):
    fields = linea.split('\"')
    return (int(fields[0]), fields[1].encode("utf8"))

nombres = sc.textFile("./Marvel/Marvel-names.txt")
nombresrdd=nombres.map(codificarnombres)

lines = sc.textFile("./Marvel/Marvel-graph.txt")

emparejar = lines.map(numerocoapariciones)
totalapariciones = emparejar.reduceByKey(lambda x,y :x + y)

flipped = totalapariciones.map(lambda xy: (xy[1], xy[0]))

maspopular = flipped.max()

nombremaspopular = nombresrdd.lookup(maspopular[1])[0]
print("Héroe más popular: \n" + str(nombremaspopular))
```

Am i missing some library? Is it a version problem? Im running Python 3.7.0 ,Pyspark 2.4.0 and writing the code on Spyder (Anaconda environment).

Comment: This might help you and I feel like maybe try no dashes for the files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334604/hadoop-java-net-urisyntaxexception-relative-path-in-absolute-uri-rsrchbase-co/25336223

Comment: @JoeA yeah I think the issue is in the file path, and im trying multiple things but with no result. I think i would need the 'mac' version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552235/loading-local-file-in-sc-textfile?rq=1

Comment: Just tried full path but got same error: "/Users/Carlos/Desktop/UEM/2018\:19/GrandesVolúmenesDatos/Marvel/Marvel-names.txt"

Comment: The useful line on the error message is `: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 2018:19` which probably tells you that there is a problem with your file path. Try to escape the path string properly

Comment: Thank you both Joe and Alexandros for your answers, it was a path issue. I'll write full answer since it may be useful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different things it was the simplest of them all: a file path issue.

The original path of both my .py file and .txt files included a ':' which i've read in multiple sites can cause error when reading file paths. I just moved both the .py and the .txt to other path (Desktop, for making things 100% easy) and worked perfectly.

In the process of solving this i also came across the issue that, after updating pyspark from terminal, Anaconda Environment wont launch, so i updated python with the following command and worked like a charm again:

```
conda update python -yn root
```

(I know this last issue is offtopic but hey, I hope it helps someone someday)