# pickleFile() occur relative path in absolute URI error

Tags: python, pyspark

before I this work, I saved my files using pyspark. cause they were so big to handling with python. saved as Pickle but seems like dir, idk.

And after works did done, I call with `sc.pickleFile(file_name)` like this, and this error occurs.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: {filename}
```

Files( DIRs? ) in one Directory, and if i entered specific one, the file names like `part-00000`, `part-00001` ...

I've changed pythonpath, or work env ( opened jupyter in Dir ). But All doesn't work
i can't handling my files :(

[image]

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. `java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: {filename}`. So, when you call `sc.pickleFile(file_name)`, make sure `file_name` is an absolute path.

Comment: I already put absolute path to file_name. But same error comes :(

Comment: i solve this... omg i'm so stupid.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334604/hadoop-java-net-urisyntaxexception-relative-path-in-absolute-uri-rsrchbase-co/25336223